# Передача данных между Activity

Tags: android, java

Нужно передать строку из одного Активити в другое.
Делаю в главном активити:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityScreen0.this, ActivityScreen8_pages.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
intent.putExtra("page", "news");
startActivity(intent);
```

В том в которое посылаются данные:

```
String page = getIntent().getStringExtra("page");
```

Теперь вопрос, не работает такое вот сравнение:

```
if(page == "news"){

}
```

Не могу понять почему, судя по всему, строки по какой то причине не равны, но вот по какой причине?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос решен. Я ошибся.
Для сравнения используется string.equals(string) или string.equalsIgnoreCase(string).